# Java - Disable scientific notation in JTable cells

Tags: java, swing, numbers, jtable

I have a JTable where a series of Float are displayed. For small values the cell displays the number in scientific notation. Is there a way to disable that?

Comment: are you using the correct data type? sounds like it's being implicitly cast to a float or double.

Comment: Format number is your friend.  All ways to display cells of a JTable can be overwritten.  I would tend to do the opposite of @SnakeDoc, have your numbers display as strings.

Comment: getValue is actually not overrided. If i override, how to do this?

Comment: If you follow @PeteBelford advice, you may want to implement/override the cell's comparator so that it works logically with your column. ie. if the user sorts a column ascending, you want numbers to sort properly and not be treated as Strings., etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the following page to get an insight about why it is happening: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender

Then you should pass your own `NumberFormat` instance (somehow) in to your `JTable`, and then all numbers will be formatted properly.

I think it's a good read to read through the entire `JTable` documentation if you decide to work with it for a long time and I am sure that it is mentioned there how to apply the `NumberFormat`.